# Button Position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My question is how to handle the position on screen (WPF) of 4 buttons. They are organzed vertically such as:

BUTTON1
BUTTON2
BUTTON3
BUTTON4

Since there are 24 possible order combinations (One might be visible while another might not under certain circumstances) I would like to know whether do you have a smart solution to order them.

Basically I have to hide the inactive button and re-arrange the margin in the screen in order to show to the user the new order.

Actually I was dealing with the System.Windows.Visibility. For example if the BUTTON1 is not active the BUTTON2 has to be the first in the order and so on...

I hope that my question is clear and to receive some useful tips.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using a StackPanel and watch this [link](http://www.wpfnewbie.com/2010/08/04/how-to-horizontally-align-wpf-controls-in-stackpanel/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the visibility to the active property and you dont have to write any backend code. The binding should handle everything for you

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button1" Visibility={Binding IsButton1Active,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}/>
```

and so on.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other problem with this. Please mark as answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: I have to be careful with this comment as I don't want to give the wrong impression... to be clear, I'm *not* asking for my answer to be accepted. However, how can this answer be the accepted answer to this question? It doesn't answer the question at all... the question author's question was *My question is how to handle the position on screen (WPF) of 4 buttons*. This answer says *Bind the visibility to the active property*... how can that be the correct answer? Can you either actually answer this question, or edit the question so that they match?

Comment: Hi Sheridan Sorry if i gave a wrong impression with my post but I thought the author was already handling the positioning of the buttons as in one of the posts   'This is what I am doing right now, but I would like to avoid to use nested if or a long switch to handle all the 24 combinations. '. When he/she said the buttons are arranged vertically, I assumed a stackpanel was being used. I thought the main problem was with a lot of if statements which were hiding and showing the buttons as and when required so Binding would have solved the problem without using any of the backend code

Comment: @Krishna, don't worry, there's absolutely no problem from you. Your answer clearly helped the question author... they just seem to have asked the wrong question and it's a bit strange having this miss-match.

Comment: Sorry Guys but let me say that all of them were very useful, I figured out thanks your help how to solve my problem and I got it mixing more all less all the provided solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the [`StackPanel` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) on MSDN for full details. This `Panel` control will automatically move the `Button` positions as you switch their `Visibility` property value between `Visible` and `Collapsed`... it is important that you use the `Collapsed` value rather than the `Hidden` value, as the `Collapsed` setting will not reserve that `Button`'s space when it is hidden:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
</StackPanel>
```

You could just as easily use a `Grid Panel` to do the same:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" ... />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" ... />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" ... />
    <Button Grid.Row="3" ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Very useful indeed, I do not have to deal with margins and so on... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Visibility.Collapsed to hide the button which you are going to hide

Comment: This is what I am doing right now, but I would like to avoid to use nested if or a long switch to handle all the 24 combinations.

Comment: then you should bind the visibility in view model use it you should also mention that u have used this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Vertical"`. You won't have to deal with margins. Set `Visibility` to `Collapsed`. Value of `Hidden` will preserve space for every button, even if not visible.

Comment: -1 The question author said *They are organzed vertically*, but you suggested that they set `Orientation="Horizontal"`... I'll be happy to remove this down vote if you correct your error.